# XML cdata tgas being erased when there's input in Russian

Tags: php, xml, cdata

I have a very strange problem which I will be very thankful if someone would help me with.

I have a form that has a textarea whose content is later transferred to a page that has a line like this (using DOM with php to change data on an XML file):

> $dom->getElementsByTagName("page")->item($itemNum)->getElementsByTagName("lang")->item(1)->getElementsByTagName("text")->item(0)->firstChild->data=$_POST['rus0'];

The XML file in question looks like this:

> < text>< ![CDATA[ Text from the form
>   ]]>< /text>

The strange thing happens when I upload it to the server and try to input Russian text, in which case it erases the CDATA completely and results in

> < text/>

And, weirdly, the thing works fine on my own server emulator (I'm using MAMP with php 5, the remote server also has php 5) - in my machine inputing Russian works fine.

Any ideas what's going on in this?

Comment: Is the character encoding correct? If the remote server uses e.g. Latin-1, it is possible that it just drops unknown characters...

Answer (score 0):

The input text is probably in the wrong encoding.